# how to limit star-count on Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an anonymous social media app with a universal feed. I want to limit the likes on a post to one per user, but I don't know how to limit the likes of each user. This is my current code:

```
    class story
var text = ""
var numberoflikes = 0
var user = Auth.auth().currentuser!

iboulet weak var : likebutton : uibutton
iboulet weak var: storylabel : uilabel

var story: story! {
didSet {
storylabel.text = story.text
likebutton.setTitle(" /("story.numberoflikes)", for: []}}
}

ibaction func likedidtouch: (_ sender: AnyObject) {
story.like()
llikebutton.settitle(" \(story.numberoflikes)", for: []}}
}}

extension story {
func like() {
if like() set user = false
else set user = true
numberoflikes += 1 
ref.child("numberoflikes").setValue(numberoflikes
}
}
```

What do I need to change in order to limit the likes of each user to one?

my database model, i have:
"stories"> "text", "numberoflikes"

I would really appreciate any help you can give me on this

Comment: If you store the users uid (as suggested in the current answer), it's not going to be anonymous.

Comment: doesnt each user carry a universal user identifcation device (uuid). so is what youre telling me that firebase anonymous users cant be differetiated in firebase (ie. different likes from diffeent users)?

Comment: do you know anyway i can authenticate anonymous users for likes?

Comment: Each user is identified with unique uid. To do that you will need to implement Anonymous Authentication and then use the uid that's created to identifiy that user. However, techncially, the user can auth several times anonymously which would skew the likes. I don't recall what the limit is per IP but it's several.

Comment: ok, i implemented login anonymously and so far it works. how do i call the users id?

Comment: as in what is the code to identify the anonymous user?

Comment: Once the *.signInAnonymously* has been called the uid can be obtained from  *let user = authResult.user.uid* and is covered here [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a similar platform. What I did was storing the user votes in my database as well.

[image: vote]

Within each user's node they have their vote values for every single post.
So lets say you want to have buttons with highlights like below. You will have to fetch the postVotes node for that user from the tree, loop over the postVotes object and assign highlights depending on each post's vote value.

[image]

Lastly you should compare user's old vote that you keep on the firebase with his new vote.

```
let incrementBy
let userVote

if (currentVote === newVote * -1) {
  incrementBy = newVote * 2
  userVote = newVote
}
else if(currentVote === 0) {
  incrementBy = newVote
  userVote= newVote
}
else {
  incrementBy = newVote * -1
  userVote= 0
}

// update your totalvote value on your firebase by incrementBy
// swap your firebase uservote value on that post with userVote
```

Comment: great answer! how would i be able to add the uservotes to my code. may i ask what your code looks like?

Comment: I dont know this will help since I am using javascript but just so you have an idea I do something like this just after I set the actual vote value on firebase.
    let userRef = db.ref(`users/${uid}/postVotes`)

        userRef.child(postKey).update({
          vote: vote
        })

Comment: that is the problem i need help with i don't know what the uid is. is that similar in every programming language because? i dont understand how to call the uid on xcode or firebase? where can i find it?

Comment: i added among var: text and var: numberoflikes, var: isliked and i set it as a bool instead of string or int, so when a user touches the likeboutton ,isliked is set to true. my wuestion now is how do i tell my xcode to disbale the numberoflikes for the specific uid for numberoflikes when an anonymous suer likes something ebcuase the way i have ti set up now a user can increasly like something becuase =+ means adding infintley. i want it so when a specific uid like a post they can not like the same post anymore baused on their uid?

Comment: this is where i am stuck: extension func like() { numberoflikes += 1 ref.child("numberoflikes").setvalue(numberoflikes) } and then i added just now right under that another func: func isliked() { isliked = true (this is where i am stuck where i am stuck anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: i have stories (i think by childbyautoid) then text: hello and another value keypair next to text is numberoflikes: 3

Comment: Since you are using firebase do you have a user table like I do on the image above?

aand do you store the uservotes in firebase as well as incrementing the total vote count?

Comment: do you ahve an email becuase i have a chromebook and it will nto let me pos tthe screen shot. anyway besides the locked i have numberoflikes instead of postvotes so yes

Comment: please i am really close to finishing a project ive been workign on for 2 years, if you could help me through email i would eb completed?

Comment: so you can just do the same thing as I did. when the user votes you store his vote inside postVotes and whenever he votes again on the same post you compare his old vote with new vote and modify the totalvote number accordingly

Comment: i dont see how you did that on your table. it just shows 2 different users voting, how can you tell if the user voted twice on the same post?

Comment: you put a firebase listener to that table then whenever user tries to vote you compare his new vote with whatever is in the table

Comment: thank you very much ,but can i ask where you got all these vraibles from. was this from your code. should i create my own variables? becuase i didnt see you declare newvote or currentvote or was this just an outline?

Comment: That just to explain what you should be doing.
current vote is what you fetched from firebase postvotes
newvote value is whichever vote button user has pushed now

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to approach this but here are two. Either way, start with this Firebase structure.

```
posts
  some_post_id
     post: "I like pizza"
     votes
      uid_0: true
      uid_2: true
      uid_5: true
```

1) See if the voting user has already voted by checking to see if their [Anonymous User Id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) (UID) already exists

In essence, when a user votes for a post, capture their uid and write it to the votes node with a true value if it doesn't already exist.

Before writing, check to see if they already voted

```
let thisUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
let refToCheck = postsRef.child("some_post_id").child("votes").child(thisUid!)

refToCheck.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("you already voted for this post")
    } else {
        print("no uid found, adding a vote")
        refToCheck.setValue(true)
    }
})
```

note this needs error checking but is functional.

2) Use Firebase Rules to allow a write only the uid (key) doesn't already exist within the votes node. Essentially it will deny the write if the uid already exists). I like #1 better but that is an alternative.

If you are not familiar with rules there are a lot of options so take a look a the [Firebase Rules Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) first.