# Swift Firebase preventing users from voting multiple times and displaying the average rating

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In summary, I'm making a restaurant rating app in Swift that lets its users to make comments and give ratings (from a 1 to 5-star rating scale) to restaurants. The app doesn't require a sign-up screen or a login, users can directly vote and comment on restaurants. I have two questions.

I can successfully manage to get a particular user's rating on a certain restaurant and store it in my Firebase database BUT the thing is that I can't stop the same user from voting multiple times. I only want every user to vote only once, they can comment as much as they want but their star ratings should be limited exclusively to one. I think it has something to do with their uids, but I couldn't manage to solve the problem. Also, how can I display average rating of the restaurant? I mean how and where should I keep it and display it?

Here is my code so far. I'd appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let commentsReference = ref.child(locationName).child("comments")
    let newCommentID = commentsReference.childByAutoId().key
    let newCommentReference = commentsReference.child(newCommentID)
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Sign in failed:", error.localizedDescription)

        } else {
            let user = authResult?.user
            let isAnonymous = user?.isAnonymous  // true
            let uid = user?.uid
            // print ("Signed in with uid:", authResult!.uid)
            var currentUserID = uid
            if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                currentUserID = currentUser.uid
            }
            newCommentReference.setValue(["uid": currentUserID as Any, "userRating":self.ratingStackView.starsRating]) { (error, ref) in 

            //ratingStakView.starsRating successfully returns the number of stars the user has chosen from my other viewController

                  if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not even a single person can help me?? :-(

Comment: This type of question has been asked a LOT here on SO. Remember we are not paid to help - we volunteer to help. Sometimes it take a little while for us  to evaluate questions. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020942/swift-how-to-add-5-star-ratings-for-users-to-vote-using-firebase/52021970#comment91004110_52021970) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811974/how-to-limit-star-count-on-firebase/51812363#51812363) and [even this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811974/how-to-limit-star-count-on-firebase/51886312#51886312).

Comment: Bottom line is if you want to enforce what users can do, you have to have some control over who they are. If you use registered users (recommended) it's easy as you can track everything via their UID internally. If you use anonymous authentication you loose some of that traceability. If you use no authentication then all bets are off and you have no control. I would suggest registering users as that's generally best practice IMO

Comment: So quick question: Do you have the user's UID or are you trying to figure out how to generate one for each person? Second question, do you have nodes that you could get all the values of the ratings?

Comment: When a user is created, they are assigned a unique user id (uid) that you can use for all kinds of tasks - including rules and/or code that would prevent them from voting more than once (for example).

Comment: @Jay thanks for the response, I'm sorry I didn't mean to disrespect in any way. I will keep searching I guess. I don't want my users to spend time creating accounts and logging in, thus I believe I'm going to use anonymous authentication

Comment: @Torewin yes even though they don't register or login, I can see their specific uid via autonomous authentication. That was how I thought I could distinguish those who voted and those who didn't but don't know how to implement the code

Comment: So if you can confirm that they are in fact unique (and not unique to the session) then all you would do is have a node, call it Ratings, and inside it has a dictionary (userUID: 3) and the value would correspond to the rating it was given - then when a user goes to review, all you do is check if the ID exsists in the dictionary - if it does then they can't rate.